# PHP array with both a numbered index and named index?

Tags: php, arrays

I would think this would be easier to find but I've been scouring google with no luck.  Can you create an array with both a numbered and named index? I know it has to be possible because mysqli_fetch_array returns one, but I can't find any reference to it. 
Thanks.

Comment: To access a 'named' index, associative array via an integer: `$keys = array_keys($my_arr);`
`$my_arr[$keys[1]] = "element_value";` `[1]` being the integer. This requires less memory than storing an array with both an integer and named element, plus it makes manipulation/editing simple.

Answer (score 3):

As per [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.
>
> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to it:

```
$x = array();
$x['foo'] = 'bar';
$x[1] = 'baz';
```

Use any key you want. As long as whatever you're using for a key is an int or a valid string, it can be a key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. PHP arrays can have mixed keys (strings and integers). A reference to it can be found in the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Check Example #3:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
        100   => -100,
        -100  => 100,
    );
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

outputs:

```
array(4) {
    ["foo"] => string(3) "bar"
    ["bar"] => string(3) "foo"
    [100] => int(-100)
    [-100] => int(100)
}
```